# how to update pg_dump on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am trying to export my rds postgresql database.  I'm using elastic beanstalk.  `sudo yum install postgresql` installs version 9.2-1.20 on my ec2 instance.  RDS uses version 9.3 so I am unable to run `pg_dump` Is there a way to install version 9.3 of postgresql (or just pg_dump) on my ec2 instance?  Any tips would be welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're on the amazon linux ami, issue the following to get postgresql 9.3 installed:

`$ yum install http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-redhat93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm
$ yum install postgresql93-server postgresql93-contrib`

the version should then be 9.3.5:
`$ pg_basebackup -V
pg_basebackup (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5`

**UPDATE:**
The Amazon repository currently doesn't hold postgresql 9.3 so you can't `yum update` your postgresql on the machine.
I have worked around it by installing manually. Here're the steps I followed from the documentation:

`sudo yum install -y bison-devel readline-devel zlib-devel openssl-devel wget
sudo yum groupinstall -y 'Development Tools'
wget  ftp://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v9.3.2/postgresql-9.3.2.tar.bz2
bzip2 -d postgresql-9.3.2.tar.bz2
tar -xvf postgresql-9.3.2.tar
cd postgresql-9.3.2
./configure
gmake
sudo gmake install`

And now you have `/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_dump`

I sent a support ticket to amazon. will update when they reply.

**UPDATE 2:**
Here's the reply from Amazon support:
1. show the current version:
rpm -qa | grep postgres
2. remove it:
rpm -e postgresql92-libs-9.2.9-1.46.amzn1.x86_64 postgresql92-9.2.9-1.46.amzn1.x86_64 postgresql92-devel-9.2.9-1.46.amzn1.x86_64
3. yum list postgresql93
4. yum  install postgresql93.x86_64
5. Then show the current version:
rpm -qa | grep postgres
postgresql93-libs-9.3.5-1.52.amzn1.x86_64
postgresql93-9.3.5-1.52.amzn1.x86_64

Comment: With the second command I am getting the following error:  ```http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/redhat/rhel-2014.03-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror```

Comment: what ami are you using? try also to yum update before that. these commands worked for me on the amazon linux

Comment: Thank you @Tal for your help.  I have the following setting in ```.elasticbeanstalk/config``` ```SolutionStack=64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.7 running Ruby 2.1 (Passenger Standalone)```

Comment: I might also mention that I ran ```yum update``` before I tried the commands which you mentioned.

Comment: I updated the answer with the exact steps I took to make pg_dump work

Comment: Hi @Tal just wondering on your update 2 if this actually worked? I'm not getting anything listed on the command: yum list postgresql93

Comment: @jufemaiz are you on an amazon linux box? Here's what I get: `#  yum list postgresql93
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Repodata is over 2 weeks old. Install yum-cron? Or run: yum makecache fast
Available Packages
postgresql93.x86_64                                                   9.3.5-1.52.amzn1                                                    amzn-main`